# getting the value, which a pointer is pointing to

Tags: c, pointers

I am having some trouble with an assignment. I am trying to read the lines from a txt file (line by line) split the values and calculate the quadratic formula from them; the lines always contain a, b and c. However, I came to a problem where it looks like when I come to the formula the values seem to be the pointer position instead of the value assigned. I don't think the `finalArrayOfValues` should be a `char*` but the code wouldn't compile without it. Is there any way to retrieve the value from the pointer or should I try a different solution?

Apologies in advance if this is trivial (coming from javascript and python) I am quite new to c,
Thank you.

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  double a;
  double b;
  double c;
  double d;
  char arrayOfValues[100][128];
  char lines[128];
  char *finalArrayOfValues[3];
  int i = 0;
  double root1, root2;
  FILE *file; /* declare a FILE pointer  */
  file = fopen("QFData1.txt", "r");

  int count = 0;
  while (fgets(lines, 128, file)) {
    strcpy(arrayOfValues[count], lines);
    printf("line %d: %s\n", count, arrayOfValues[count]);
    count++;
  }
  char *string = arrayOfValues[1];
  char *token = strtok(string, ",");
  // loops through the string to extract all other tokens
  for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
    finalArrayOfValues[i] = token;
    printf(" %s\n", token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    i++;
  }

  printf(" %s\n", finalArrayOfValues[0]);
  printf(" %s\n", finalArrayOfValues[1]);
  printf(" %s\n", finalArrayOfValues[2]);

  a = finalArrayOfValues[0] - "0";
  b = finalArrayOfValues[1] - "0";
  c = finalArrayOfValues[2] - "0";

  printf(" %f\n", a);
  printf(" %f\n", b);
  printf(" %f\n", c);

  d = b * b - (4 * a * c);
  printf(" %f\n", d);

  // real roots
  root1 = (-b + sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
  root2 = (-b - sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);

  printf("First root = %.2lf\n", root1);
  printf("Second root = %.2lf\n", root2);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are assigning the result from `strtok` to `finalArrayOfValues[i]`, then yes, each element of the array should be a string (a pointer to one or more chars somewhere in memory). Note that these addresses are still inside the `arrayOfValues`. However, this part is horribly wrong: `finalArrayOfValues[0] - "0"`, you are subtracting the address of the string literal `"0"` from `finalArrayOfValues[0]`. You probably want to convert the string into a `double` (e.g. using `sscanf`).

Comment: C is a low level language. You need to use a conversion function to transform a string representation of a number into a number. Candidates are `strtod` or the `scanf` family functions (`sscanf` to read from a string). You should show a line from the input text if you need more help.

Comment: sscanf worked and makes sense. Thank you all for your help.